# sql error using between operator with date between two dates

Tags: mysql, sql, date

i have an events table  having start date and end date  I am trying retrieve all the records by giving a date that is between start and end dates.

eg :

```
SELECT * 
FROM   `events` 
WHERE  '2017-01-29' BETWEEN start_date='2017-01-28' 
                    AND     end_date='2017-01-31'
```

but response is syntax error can any one help me to finish the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just list the columns.

```
WHERE '2017-01-29' BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
```

The values come from the table, you don't put them into the query.

Answer (score 2):

According to mysql documentation (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) the syntax for BETWEN is

```
expr BETWEEN min AND max
```

it is not

```
expr BETWEEN blabla=min AND stuff=max
```

Also, it is rather pointless to be using constants in all three expressions, because in this case the result will be known in advance (either always TRUE or always FALSE) without having to consult the values in your table.

It is kind of hard to give you an example without knowing the structure of your table, but what you probably want is something like

```
WHERE '2017-01-29' BETWEEN start_date
                   AND     end_date
```

(assuming `start_date` and `end_date` are columns in your table)

or something like

```
WHERE  some_column BETWEEN '2017-01-28' 
                   AND    '2017-01-31'
```

(assuming `some_column` is a column in your table.)

Comment: can u give any suggestion to finish my requirment

Comment: @sivasandeepgarapati Doesn't my answer do that?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're trying to find all the rows where a date is 2017-01-29, and so, your query could be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   `events` 
WHERE   
date = '2017-01-29';
```

If, however, you want all rows with date between 2017-01-28                    and 2017-01-31, then you could do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   `events` 
WHERE   
date BETWEEN '2017-01-28' AND '2017-01-31';
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting `2017-01-29` before `WHERE`, put the name of the field you want to filter by date, such as `EventDate` (or whatever your field is named).

Comment: I think he wants all events where that date is between the start and end.